# Transparent video in Android AR Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, augmented-reality, alpha-transparency

I am looking to solve the problem of displaying a transparent video in the AR scenes using Unity ARFoundation and Android platform.

I mean, accurately with a simple effect presented for the iOS platform: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vralbqaeqrk

In the normal 3D application I use the transcoded .Webm file and I achieve the intended purpose.
Using the same solution in the AR (ARCore) scene  the background color is visible.

Can you use specialized/dedicated  assets? Or should I stop dreaming about such a result using Unity and Android?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please share your research.

Comment: @Ruzihm I did similar example to presented by Digvijaysinh Gohil below in his answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your video clip does have an alpha channel then just click `keep alpha` property in video importing section and hit apply. However it will only show if your video does have an alpha.

[image: Video import settings]

Then just attach a `Video player` component to the gameobject which has a `Mesh renderer`.

[image: Video player on Cube]

Make sure the Render mode is `Material override` and `Material property` tells unity on which map of the material video output will be displayed.

If you want to play it on UI, just make a render texture and assign it to `RawImage` and assign the Video player with following settings.

[image: Video player on Raw image]

Lastly make sure the render texture you created does have support for alpha.

[image: Render texture]

Comment: Thak you. Yes, it works (I did it my tests) in ordinary 3D scene but it dosen't in AR scele.

Comment: In your ar scene, after following the above steps, are you able to see transparent video in the play mode inside unity editor? If not then I need more information on how you have setup your ar scene?